# Using MVVM Light and AgFx together in a Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, restsharp, reactiveui, agfx

So I'm just starting on Windows Phone app development and I don't have any experience working with Silverlight or WPF (in fact any XAML based platform) before. Naturally I started with doing a lot of research and learning before I jump in and I must say it is a bit overwhelming.

The things I've decided on is that I want my app to follow the MVVM pattern and since it would constantly be communicating with a REST web service, I would like to have a good caching framework in place as well.

I'm currently looking at MVVM Light, RestSharp, Silverlight Toolkit, Facebook C# SDK, and Twitterizer as the primary libraries to use. (I only need Facebook and Twitter for authentication and authorization actually so may end up not using the libraries at all and let RestSharp handle that as well).

The real problem is that since it is my first time, I cant really decide between going with something like MVVM Light and RestSharp which has some good features like making MVVM simple to use or AgFx, which I hear is really good at data caching. Also I've seen Rx being mentioned enough times to consider it as an option as well but from what I've read up till now, it wont work with MVVM Light or AgFx. Though there is the ReactiveUI framework as well.

Any ideas or recommendations on what platform to take would really be appreciated here. Like I mentioned before, my app would completely rely on the REST backend and will actively be playing with the Location Service on the phone (my app is location based actually).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ReactiveUI works quite well with MVVM Light. Here's an [article on how to do it](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/04/04/using-reactiveui-with-mvvm-light-or-any-other-framework/)

Comment: I've postponed the idea of Rx for now and decided to only go with MVVM Light for ViewModels and make the models implement AgFx when loading in data through a service. I'm still stuck at this part though since it complicates things quite a bit so unless someone can point out a better way, I'll have to re-evaluate the advantage of AgFx.